# Jest.fn() does not update global variable

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to re-render with **updated** variable. I can be able to call handleMenuCollapse mock function but 'collapsed' variable does not change.( It should be false but it's still true)

A simple code will explain my issue;

```
   let collapsed: boolean = true
   const handleMenuCollapse = jest.fn(() => (collapsed = !collapsed))
   
   test('Click to collapse menu icon and then menu side should be collapsed', () => {
    
   const { getByTestId, rerender } = render(
                                            <Header
                                              collapsed={collapsed}
                                              handleOnCollapse={handleMenuCollapse}>
                                            </Header>
                                           )
    const unfoldedMenuIcon = getByTestId('unfold-menu-icon')

    fireEvent.click(unfoldedMenuIcon)
    expect(handleMenuCollapse).toHaveBeenCalled() // function is called.
    expect(collapsed).toBe(false) // but 'collapsed' still true

    rerender(
          <Header
             collapsed={collapsed}
             handleOnCollapse={handleMenuCollapse}
          ></Header>
       )
}
```

The question is; Why 'collapsed' still true?

Comment: have you tried waitfor?
https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro/

Comment: I tried waitFor without await. But I think I don't need this because, I can see function is called before expecting false collapsed. @aleEspinosaM

Comment: where does `_collapsed` come from ?

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake when I copy to here, I fixed. @aquinq

Comment: Does the `Header` component modify the `collapsed` variable internally in any way? Could you share its code?